# Anotação JPA @OneToMany ou ManytoOne?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Possuo a Classe Report

```
public class Report{

    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "idpai", referencedColumnName = "id" )
    private List<Report> subReports

    getters e setters...
}
```

A minha duvida é como realizar a anotação da forma correta, desta maneira como esta acima estou recebendo:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on br.com.koinonia.habil.model.user.Report.subReportProvider references an unknown entity: java.util.List
```

Sendo a lista de SubReport um array da propria classe Report, ou seja, é a mesma tabela.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se **UM** Relatório possui **VÁRIOS** subrelatórios então a anotação que deve ser usada é `@OneToMany`

```
public class Report{

    private String nome;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Report> subReports

    getters e setters...
}
```

Uma `List` não pode ser considerada como **UM**, então as anotações `@OneToOne` e `@ManyToOne` não se aplicam nesse caso.

Como os subrelatórios é um relacionamento bidirecional para mesma classe Relatório então você deve mapear os dois lados do relacionamento, o `@JoinColumn` deve ser aplicado na coluna que representa o relatório pai.

```
public class Report {

    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idpai")
    private Report masterReport;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="masterReport")
    private List<Report> subReports

    getters e setters...
}
```

Comment: Sucesso arrasador, obrigado!

Comment: Olá Andre, preciso de ajuda em outra situação,